# Redirect keyboard input to child control in .net

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a pretty large .net forms application and I want to be able to capture keyboard input at the form level and redirect it to a textbox, even though it doesn't have focus.  I've set the form KeyPreview flag and I can capture the key events with no problem.  I can even send characters to the textbox but I don't know how to handle things like the cursor keys, delete, backspace etc.

I tried to send focus to the textbox in the forms OnKeyDown method, in the hope that it would then redirect the key press but that didn't work - it seems like the Focus operation is too slow.

Any bright ideas?

Cheers,

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are handling the event at the form level, then altering the text of the TextBox.  Instead try re-raising the KeyDown event on the TextBox itself.

Comment: Thanks for your input Justin, much appreciated.  I am handling it at the form level first because that's the only way I can reliably capture the key presses if the TB doesn't have focus.